# Returning pointers from C++ to C# using SWIG

Tags: c#, c++, swig

How could I return pointers to C# from C++ using SWIG?
For example, I have following:

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        void* buffer(); // return pointer to internal buffer
        int *somethingElse();
};
```

How could I write swig interface file to successfully use this class from c#?

Comment: What is the C++ library?  Is it .NET?

Answer (score 1):

Use C++/CLI to wrap your C++ class. In your C++/CLI class return appropriately typed objects.

For example:

```
//[untested! not production quality. Just to illustrate a point]
ref class MyClassWrapper
{
    MyClass * m_pMyClass;

    public:
    MyClassWrapper():m_pMyClass(NULL)
    {
        m_pMyClass = new MyClass();
    }   

    ~MyClassWrapper()
    {
        this->!MyClassWrapper();
    }

    array<byte>^ AccessBuffer()
    {
        m_pMyClass->buffer();
        array<byte>^ buf = gcnew array<byte>(buffer_length);
        ...
        //Copy elements to buf
        ...
        return buf;
    }

    !MyClassWrapper()
    {
        delete m_pMyClass;
        m_pMyClass = NULL;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you Indeera! Although that's correct, I need to expose functionality of C++ code (a huge API) to C# using Swig. I avoid writing wrappers manually, thus decided to use SWIG. Currently I've stuck at functions and methods returning pointers to static variables and members. I couldn't find how to write swig .i file to express those functions and methods.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
%apply void *VOID_INT_PTR { void * }
```

to generate void* as System.IntPtr in C#. But i am now really sure if it's that what you want.